# Why my Flutter BottomSheet gives me a GestureDetector error?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, gesturedetector

I have a problem with this BottomSheet, it works fine but as soon as I tap on it, I will get an error...

```
bottomSheet: showBottomSheet
        ? BottomSheet(
            enableDrag: true,
            onClosing: () {},
            builder: (ctx) => Container(
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          )
```

Why I am getting this error?

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The getter 'status' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: status

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _BottomSheetState._dismissUnderway 
package:flutter/…/material/bottom_sheet.dart:187
#2      _BottomSheetState._handleDragEnd 
package:flutter/…/material/bottom_sheet.dart:204
#3      DragGestureRecognizer._checkEnd.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/gestures/monodrag.dart:439
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
...
Handler: "onEnd"
Recognizer: VerticalDragGestureRecognizer#22607
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    start behavior: start
```

What do I need to add?
I guess I need to add an OnDragEnd function?
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 3):

As commented, just put `enableDrag: false,` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

The `BottomSheet` widget requires an `animationController` if `enableDrag` is set to `true`.

So:

```dart
bottomSheet: showBottomSheet
        ? BottomSheet(
            enableDrag: true,
            animationController: BottomSheet.createAnimationController(this),
            onClosing: () {},
            builder: (ctx) => Container(
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          )
```

If you get errors about `this` not being a `TickerProvider`, you can add the `TickerProviderStateMixin`:

```dart
class _MyViewState extends State<MyView> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
```

(All that being said, the docs for `BottomSheet` say that it in general shouldn’t be used directly. I’m personally not yet sure whether one should do the above solution vs. using `showBottomSheet`.)